# How to understand "tables" in Hierarchical Dirichlet Process(HDP)?

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, lda

In [Hierarchical Dirichlet Process](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf), the author gives an interpretation of HDP using Chinese Restaurant Franchise. It said that each restaurant has many tables and different tables may share a common dish in one restaurant. The dish here we can regarded as a topic in the document, then how to understand tables in every document? I think different tables should order different dishes, if two tables with the same dish, then why not merge them into one? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Chinese Restaurant Franchise (CRF), each document is a restaurant, each word is a customer, and cluster parameters are dishes served to tables from a global menu. A customer enters a restaurant and sits at a table with probability proportional to the number of customers already at a table, or sits at a new table with probability alpha. New tables are then assigned a particular dish with probability proportional to the number of tables already serving that dish, or a new dish with probability gamma.

Thus, for every customer we have an index that maps the customer to the table and for every table we have an index that maps the table to one of the dishes. A Gibbs sampling algorithm, first samples tables associated with data, and then samples dishes associated with each table. For more details see [Yee Whye Teh's implementation](https://github.com/tdhopper/teh-npbayes).